# Polybase: Azure Sql DB cannot import blob storage

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server, polybase

Is it true that Azure SQL cannot import blob storage? (SQLDW can and also stand alone instance)

as given in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-versioned-feature-summary?view=sql-server-ver15), it cannot. But the document is from 2018. Has things changed after that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure SQL Database does not have Polybase but it does have `BULK INSERT`, eg

```
BULK INSERT Product
FROM 'data/product.dat'
WITH ( DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureBlobStorageAccount');
```

See this question for more details and an example:

[Create a table in Azure SQL Database from Blob Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41767573/create-a-table-in-azure-sql-database-from-blob-storage)

Main page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlserverstorageengine/loading-files-from-azure-blob-storage-into-azure-sql-database

Answer (score 0):

It is true. PolyBase is not part of Azure SQL DB . And the document in your question is the latest.