# Bulk Insert Parquet Files in Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to load a parquet file into Azure SQL Database based on an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66147634/4802288) on SO. However, I'm getting a syntax error. I don't see much documentation on Microsoft website or enough information on Google. So, seeking help from experts here. FYI - I have already created the DATA_SOURCE.

**Creating External Data Source:**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [my_azure_blob_storage]
WITH (
        LOCATION = N'abfss://xxxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net', 
        CREDENTIAL = [myblobStorage] ,
        TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE
);
```

**Doing BULK INSERT:**

```
BULK INSERT [dbo].[Employees]
FROM 'gold/employees'
WITH
    (
        DATA_SOURCE = 'my_azure_blob_storage',
        FORMAT = 'PARQUET',
        FIRSTROW = 2
    );
```

And the error I am getting is:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
> Incorrect syntax near 'FORMAT'.

Answer (score 5):

Currently the only FORMAT supported in [BULK INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or [OPENROWSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is CSV.

You can use Azure Data Factory or Spark to bulk load SQL Server from a parquet file, or to prepare a CSV file for BULK INSERT or OPENROWSET.

UPDATE: Support for Delta and Parquet have ben added to [OPENROWSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#m-use-openrowset-to-access-several-delta-files-from-azure-data-lake-gen2) SQL Server 2022.

Comment: David - thanks for the response. Is MSFT considering adding this feature to Azure SQL in the near future? Also, when you say Spark, are you referring to Databricks?

Comment: Increasing support for Parquet across the ecosystem is something MSFT is working on, but there have been no roadmap announcements on this AFAIK.  Azure Databricks or Synapse Spark (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-overview) are the two managed Spark services on Azure.  Although Spark is an Apache project and you can install it wherever you want.