# SQL Server managed instance try to access parquet files on blob storage

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage

I have a SQL Server Managed Instance in Azure and have a lot of parquet files on my Blob Storage.
I tried to create an external table linked to these files, but I can't.
After followed a tutorial on how-to create an external table, I had problems creating a **file format** on SQL. I used the sintax:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT MyParquetFormat
WITH (
    FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT,
    FORMAT_OPTIONS(
    FIELD_TERMINATOR = '|',
    STRING_DELIMITER = '"',
    ENCODING = 'UTF8'
    )
);
```

When running this command received a msg:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> Incorrect syntax near 'EXTERNAL'.

I tried to find some Azure documentation about the connection between SQL Server Managed Instance and Blob Storage. I would like to know if this is possible.

Comment: According to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66123032/error-while-creating-external-file-format-in-azure-sql-database you should try this instead. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=dedicated Then perhaps raise a document issue on the page since it doesn't see to be supported in managed instance.

Comment: You might also want to check your compatability level in case you upgrade from on prem and you are stuck in an old version

Comment: Are you sure you're using an Azure SQL Managed Instance and not, perhaps, an Azure SQL Database?

Comment: as per other learned comments use `SELECT @@VERSION` to confirm exactly what you are running in

Comment: The result of @@version is : "Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Jan 12 2023 05:25:39   Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation "

Comment: That's Azure SQL Database, @FernandoDelago , not a managed instance. Azure SQL Database doesn't support the syntax you have tried to use, as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-file-format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=delimited).

Comment: Could you share the result of this query `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition')` .

Comment: The result of SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition') is 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version can be similar for both Azure SQL database and Azure SQL managed Instance.

> The result of SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition') is 5.

This confirms that you use Azure SQL database and not a managed instance.

[image]

**Image Reference:** [SERVERPROPERTY (Transact-SQL)  | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/serverproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

- External file format is not supported in Azure SQL database.
- To copy data from blob storage to Azure SQL database, you use either **bulk insert T-SQL** command or **Open rowset**.

**Step:1 Create Database scoped credentials**

If Azure blob storage is not public, create database scoped credentials. Otherwise, skip to next step.

```sql
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL <credential-name>
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET = '<sas-value>';
```

**Step:2 Create External data source**

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE <datasource-name>
WITH ( TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
       LOCATION = 'https://<storage-account>.blob.core.windows.net',
       CREDENTIAL= <credential-name>);
```

If your blob is public, you can remove credential option in the above query.

**Step:3**

```sql
BULK INSERT product FROM '<path>' WITH 
( DATA_SOURCE = '<datasource-name>');
```

or

```sql
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '<path>', DATA_SOURCE = '<datasource-name>'
) as products;
```

[image]

**Reference**:
[Loading files from Azure Blob storage into Azure SQL Database | Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/preview-loading-files-from-azure-blob-storage-into-sql-database/)